# FullCalendar just wont display JSON feed

Tags: php, json, fullcalendar

sorry to post this but have been struggling now for 8 days and really hope someone can help as I am at the end. I have json.html & xxjson-events.php in same directory, both file content posted below.

**json.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    eventSources: [

        // your event source
        {
            url: '/xxjson-events.php' // use the `url` property
        }

    ]

});

</script>
```

**xxjson-events.php**

```
   <?php
    mysql_select_db($database_ghl_portal, $ghl_portal);
$query_rsXXCal = "SELECT * FROM events";
$rsXXCal = mysql_query($query_rsXXCal, $ghl_portal) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsXXCal = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsXXCal);
$totalRows_rsXXCal = mysql_num_rows($rsXXCal);mysql_select_db($database_ghl_portal, $ghl_portal);
$query_rsXXCal = "SELECT * FROM events";
$rsXXCal = mysql_query($query_rsXXCal, $ghl_portal) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsXXCal = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsXXCal);
$totalRows_rsXXCal = mysql_num_rows($rsXXCal);
        $result = mysql_query($query_rsXXCal) or die(mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
             $eventsArray = array();
             $eventsArray['title'] = $row['title'];
             $eventsArray['start'] = $row['start_date'];
             $eventsArray['end'] = $row['end_date']; 
        }  
        echo json_encode($eventsArray)
    ?>
```

**json-events.php viewed in browser shows:**

```
{"title":"TEST","start":"2012-02-23 00:00:00","end":"2012-02-24 00:00:00"}
```

The calendar shows on page however data does not pull through to the calendar? has anyone any ideas at all why this could be please, really struggling with this and need to sort. I thought it may be the datetimestamp showing 00:00:00 but changed this with no success?

If it helps anyone I have uploaded a zip containing 3 files to see if it works for anyone else? http://ghldatastream.co.uk.predns.ourwindowsnetwork.com/fullcal_json.zip

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your start and end date have to be in IETF, ISO8601 or UNIX timestamp format - see http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

Comment: Hi Aldrin, many thanks for your help. I thought the date format was already UNIX timestamp, have you an example of how I should format this? Is it done in JSON or the html calendar page?

I cant seem to track down any info on how/where I should implement this change?

Thanks

Comment: it should be done in the JSON preferably. unfortunately i do not know php, but i figure you could use the function here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: This is driving me mad! On the calendar output page in javascript I added - var myFormattedDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "dd-MM-yyyy"); but it does nothing! <br> I have been on this that long I dont think I can even understand what I need to do anymore!

Comment: Hi, I now tried to format the date in mysql but still doesnt work - Added this to mysql code in json .php - "Select   events.*,   Date_Format(events.start_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s') As start_date,   Date_Format(events.end_date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s')  As end_date From   events"; Any reason why that wouldnt work, really would be nice to see a working example of this, I am baffled!

Comment: try "select event.* , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(events.start_date) as start_date,  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(events.end_date) as end_date from events"

Comment: Hi Aldrin, many thanks again. Yes I tried that, when viewing json.php in browser it displays UNIX but events still dont get pulled through to calendar! Its very odd. I would upload file as it must be something simply I am not seeing but not sure I can upload here..

Comment: Example that outputs UNIX dates but doesnt pull to calendar here if it helps anyone help me - http://ghldatastream.co.uk.predns.ourwindowsnetwork.com/fullcal_json.zip

Comment: json-event.php should be returning an array of events. so something like, [{"title":"TEST","start":"1328520897","end":"1328520897"}] should hopefully work.

Comment: Hi, yes json-event.php does output correctly, [{"title":"Visit","start":"1330077690","end":"1330081890"}] but doesn't display on calendar page.. frustrating!

Comment: well it looks good to me now. can't see what else could be wrong. are you getting any javascript errors in the console? also, i don't understand php code, but i hope you are setting the content-type to 'application/json' ?

Comment: Yes Aldrin looks fine to me too, I wonder if anyone could take my zipped code and test on their machines? To be sure I added contentType: 'application/json' into the calendar page & at top of json page, no change. On calendar page I can view the data in firebug which shows it is coming through, just wont display in the actual calendar!! Not sure how much longer I can stick with this.

Comment: Hi Aldrin, I am going to end this one & create a new post as the problem has now changed I believe from not pulling through to calendar to not displaying on calendar, I wonder if this is a bug?

Thanks